# Calculate mean of column for each row excluding the row for which mean is calculated

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, data-science

I need to calculate the mean of a certain column in DataFrame, so that means for each row is calculated excluding the value of the row for which it's calculated.

I know I can iterate each row by index, dropping each row by index in every iteration, and then calculating mean. I wonder if there's a more efficient way of doing it.

Comment: Can you create data sample with expectred output, I think [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So `mean` is `sum/size` so you can subtract `sum` of all values by column and divide by length of `DataFrame` without `1`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4]})

#slow, working only with unique values
df['b'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x: df.loc[df.a != x, 'a'].mean())
#faster
df['b1'] = (df['a'].sum() - df['a']) / (len(df) - 1)
print (df)
   a         b        b1
0  1  3.000000  3.000000
1  2  2.666667  2.666667
2  3  2.333333  2.333333
3  4  2.000000  2.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

you can `dataframe["ColumnName"].mean()` for single column, or `dataframe.describe()` for all columns